Orange in bioinformatics ENSEMBL
I would like to know f the bioinformatics widgets are updated, and where I can have more info on this tool.
Here is my use case:
I have RNASEQ data in ENSEMBL format and I want to convert them to geneids. There is a helpful online tool to do this (screenshot)
https://www.biotools.fr/human/ensembl_symbol_converter
but I would very much prefer having a widget do it inside ORANGE.
Can anybody help me?
Best

